# how to add dictionary object name to json object

Tags: python, json

I have 3 python dictionaries as below:

```
gender = {'Female': 241, 'Male': 240}
marital_status = {'Divorced': 245, 'Engaged': 243, 'Married': 244, 'Partnered': 246, 'Single': 242}
family_type = {'Extended': 234, 'Joint': 235, 'Nuclear': 233, 'Single Parent': 236}
```

I add them to a list:

```
lst = [gender, marital_status, family_type]
```

And create a `JSON` object which I need to save as a `JSON` file using `pd.to_json` using:

```
jf = json.dumps(lst, indent = 4)
```

When we look at `jf` object:

```
print(jf)
[
    {
        "Female": 241,
        "Male": 240
    },
    {
        "Divorced": 245,
        "Engaged": 243,
        "Married": 244,
        "Partnered": 246,
        "Single": 242
    },
    {
        "Extended": 234,
        "Joint": 235,
        "Nuclear": 233,
        "Single Parent": 236
    }
]
```

Is there a way to make the dictionary name as key and get output as below:

```
{
"gender": {
    "Female": 241,
    "Male": 240
},
"marital_status": {
    "Divorced": 245,
    "Engaged": 243,
    "Married": 244,
    "Partnered": 246,
    "Single": 242
},
"family_type": {
    "Extended": 234,
    "Joint": 235,
    "Nuclear": 233,
    "Single Parent": 236
}
}
```

Comment: Did you mean: `lst = {'gender': gender, 'marital_status': marital_status, 'family_type': family_type}`?

Comment: Any particular reason you are using `pd.to_json`?

Comment: @StonedTensor, is there a way I can directly save the `json` object as `.json` file in a system folder?

Comment: Yes, use `json.dump` and pass the data to the outfile that way. I will update my answer to show an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to do this manually by creating a dictionary and mapping the name to the sub_dictionary yourself.

```py
my_data = {'gender': gender, 'marital_status':marital_status, 'family_type': family_type}
```

Edit: example of [adding to an outfile](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/json-dump-in-python/) using `json.dump`

```py
with open('myfile.json','w') as wrtier:
    json.dump(my_data, writer)
```

Comment: The json file looks like this: `gender\": {\n        \"Female\": 241,\n     \"Male\": 240\n    },\n...` is that fine?

Comment: I think so, are you passing any `indent` or anything else?

Comment: Yes I am, I executed `json.dumps(my_data , indent = 4)`

Comment: Apparently it's not working, can you please let me know if there's a way to get clean output as shown in my sample output.

Comment: I see that there is an extra double quotes at the beginging and end of the json file like : `"{.....}"` could you please let me know how to exclude that and the `\` in the output file.

Comment: Do you want your file to look exactly like your output or something else? Also, do you know the difference between `dump` and `dumps` ?

Comment: ok after using `json.dump` it's fine now, realize `dumps` is stored as string, and `dump` is used to save to files.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement you can done it like this by replacing line lst

```
dict_req = {"gender":gender, "marital_status":marital_status, "family_type":family_type}
```

Comment: Almost, this gives you a `set` of three dictionaries, which I don't know if it can be done like this. Just a dictionary of three keys mapped to their variable should work